RenderDataTable in R shiny add plots
I have to display a table in R shiny with 3 types of columns

Column showing percent values
Column showing time series graph
Columns with a 1-D line showing three values between 0-1

I am trying to create the dataTable using renderDatatable and the graphs using sparkline. Can anyone share any examples for doing the same. Also any suggestions for using a different function

This site is not a coding service. Add your own attempts and add more focus to your question.

Also you have five open questions, some of them with several (up-voted) answers. Maybe it would be a good start to go back to them and react to the given answers before asking new ones again and again without responding. See also here.
